# REST/HTTP: best status code to prevent cached upload?

Tags: api, http, rest

I'm designing an API where a client `PUT`s a file to the server, but the server may already have a copy of this file and not need it re-uploaded.

I'm already planning on using `Expect: 100-continue` so that the server can inform the client before the client performs the entire, inefficient upload.

My question is, **what's the best status code to return instead of `100 Continue` in the case that the server doesn't need the upload?**

Typically, the client could send an `If-None-Match` header, and the server could respond with a `412 Precondition Failed` if there was already a match.

*But*, in my case, the de-duplication is almost an implementation detail, and I don't want the client to be concerned with knowing the de-dup'ing strategy (e.g. what the value to match is).

Would a `302 Found`, a `303 See Other`, or a `304 Not Modified` make sense?

It doesn't seem like a `4xx` is appropriate since it's not a client error, nor `5xx` since I don't want to trigger any automatic retry logic in the client.

Thanks!

Comment: How does the server know that it has the content without reading it?

Comment: That's the implementation detail. It's of course something separate from the body. In our case, it's based on a Content-MD5 header.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At least using cURL as a client, it turns out that 304 works great.

Comment: For some value of "works". It definitely isn't covered by the definition of 304.

Comment: No status code says "will prevent a client from sending the request body if they sent `Expect: 100-continue`". =) But, the spec for `Expect: 100-continue` says that *any* non-100 status code is the final status code -- i.e. the response is finished. So in this case, cURL stops sending the request with any non-100 status code. 304 works nicely for this scenario, hence it "works great".

Comment: Well, *any* final status code has that property. By using 304 for something it wasn't defined for, you essentially invented your own protocol. This may work, but has little to do with being "restful".

Answer (score 0):

From the client's point of view, the PUT succeeded. So I believe a 2xx status code would be right; such as 200 with a message body giving a status message.